# Separate server and reciever socket.io, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client, sender

I am building a chat with node.js, socket.io and vanilla javascript, not using any other frameworks at all. 
The final product, is going to be an one-to-one communication, groupchats does not have to be available. 
I have made an basic socket.io connection that works. How do i separate sender and receiver? I need to do this to be able to design my chat as i want. Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is event-driven. 
You can separate the sender and receiver using different channels or events.

```
//Emit the event called eventName
socket.emit('eventName',data)

//Listen for an event called eventName
socket.on('eventName', data)
```

If the eventName is different, they can't communicate, vice versa.